# what are gaps between individual computa shader invocation in metal gpu trace?

Tags: ios, xcode, gpu, metal

device: iphone 11
os:     ios 15.6

I have a metal applicaton on IOS where a series of computer shaders are encoded, then disptached and comiited together at last. When I capture a GPU trace of my application, however I noticed there are these gaps between each computer shader invocation. And these gaps seem to take up a big part of the GPU time.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJ1Dl.png)

I'm wondering what are these gaps and what are causing them. Since all compute dispatch commands are commiited toghether at once, these gaps shouldn't be synchronizations between cpu and GPU

PS: In my application, later compute commands mostly depend on former ones and would use the result buffer from former invocations. But as shown in the picture, bandwith and read/write buffer limiter are not high as far as I'm concerned.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kj2pZ.png)

I tried to find relevant information on apple documents and didn't find answers